# Research topics for starting and optimizing a high-traffic website

Tags: optimization, research

I bury a good deal of my ideas for fear that I don't know enough about scaling web applications and high-traffic websites. That said, I'd like to know of any general topics to research in order to ensure that your web app doesn't break / slow down when you start getting to Twitter-level traffic.

I'm looking for research topics with, preferably, additional resources.

For example: **Make sure you optimize SQL queries (see [High Performance MySQL Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449314287))**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Likely Suspects

Most likely, the things you want to pay attention to are:

- your caching tier,
- your database tier,
- your general architecture's design (if it's not designed to scale, it just won't).

### Further Reading

***Words of caution** about the resources below:*

- *Some are **generic resources**, **others are specific** to one stack or language but **still provide insight** on the types of issues to deal with and how to (try to) address or mitigate them.*
- *Some provide **general information of scalability**.*
- *Some give only **hints on basic pipeline and programming optimizations**.*
- *Some are sponsored or hosted by industry-actors, in which case conclusions and comparisons may or may not be accurate and/or impartial.*

#### Research papers

<sub>*Some papers' links may be unaccessible for you if you don't have a subscription to some publication networks.*</sub>

- [Dynamic Load-Balancing on Web-Server Systems](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=769420) [[PDF](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ecs230/reading/DLB.pdf)]
- [Web-Search for a Planet: the Google Architecture](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1196112) [[PDF](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Edbrooks/cs246-fall2004/google.pdf)]
- [High-Performance Site Design Techniques](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=832942) [[PDF](http://researcher.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-aruni/ieeeic2000.pdf)]
- [Scalability Issues for High-Performance Digital Libraries on the Web](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=502524) [[PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.6244&rep=rep1&type=pdf)]
- [Improving Performance on the Internet](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1461944) [[PDF](http://www.cecs.csulb.edu/%7Emaples/cecs474/coursenotes/ImprovingInternetPerf.pdf)]
- [Web Server Farm in the Cloud](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-10665-1_34) [[PDF](http://sites.google.com/site/huanliu/cloudcom.pdf)]
- [Observations on Tuning a Java Application for Performance and Scalability](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5571948)
- [The Akamai Network: A Platform for High-Performance Web-Applications](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1842736) [[PDF](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring12/cps214/newpapers/cdn.pdf)]

#### Books

- [Building Scalable WebSites](http://books.google.com/books?id=wIWU94zKEtYC) (Henderson, 2006)
- [Building Scalable and High-Performance Java Web-Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=1i_txiYSzvMC) (Barish, 2002)
- [Handbook of Cloud Computing](http://books.google.com/books?id=jLNGCPs6rr4C) (Furht, Escalante, 2010)
- [High-Performance WebSites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers](http://books.google.com/books?id=jRVlgNDOr60C) (Souders, 2007)
- [Architecture of Reliable Web-Applications Software](http://books.google.com/books?id=oTAM98wMpU8C) (Radaideh, Al-Ameed, 2007)

#### Articles, Blogs and Web Resources

- [Performance Tuning and Optimization of High-Traffic WebSites](http://www.juliandunn.net/2007/10/25/performance-tuning-and-optimization-of-high-traffic-websites/)
- [The Ultimate Guide to Web Optimization (Tips and Best Practices)](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-web-optimization-tips-best-practices/)
- A herd of resources on Google's [Make The Web Faster](https://developers.google.com/speed/) effort

  - like these [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/)
- [Scaling Python for High-Load WebSites](http://yougov.github.com/pycon/slides/)
- [Handling Web-Servers of High-Traffic WebSites](http://www.slideshare.net/ashfame/handling-web-servers-of-high-traffic-sites)
- [How to Scale PHP Applications](http://www.slideshare.net/e.zimuel/how-to-scale-php-applications)
- [TYPO3 Scalability for High-Traffic WebSites](http://www.slideshare.net/danospv/typo3-scalability-for-high-traffic-sites)
- [Scaling Twitter: Making Twitter 10,000 Percent Faster](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster/)
- [Scaling a High-Traffic Application: Our Journey From Java to PHP](http://www.achievers.com/techtalk/scaling-high-traffic-web-application-our-journey-java-php)
- [Notes on the Google Talk Architecture](http://highscalability.com/googletalk-architecture)

---

### Famous Last Words

While I can understand your original intuition that you should bury some projects out of fear that they won't adapt well and survive, I think that's the wrong approach. While the "build it and they will come" approach can be wrong, the "build it only once it's perfect" counter-part can be just as wrong.

You don't know if your projects will reach the critical mass where they actually need to care about these issues, so why not build them anyways?

Maybe you'll fail at first, but then you'll have learned and your next product will fare better. It's better to try it this way than to one day really have to dive in the deep end of the pool without a net, for a real product. So go ahead and give these ideas a chance.

While it's true that it's hard to make an application scalable when it hasn't been originalyl designed to be, at least you'll have an application that needs to be modified for scalability. In my book it's better than no application at all.

Comment: A very good answer. Informative and inspirational to boot. Thank you.

Comment: @user745434: You're welcome. Glad you like it.  The right way to show recognition for merit on StackExchange is by voting (on questions and answers, or even comments) and by accepting answers. If my question is the one you find the most helpful, and if you find it answers your original question correctly, you can upvote and accept it. Though for now I'd recommend you wait a bit longer, as others might come up with additional answers in the course of the next day or even week. (Note that you can vote on multiple answers, but accept only one).

Comment: Your answer is very good, but i might add that making benchmarks and small prototypes will help a lot, looking at the cold numbers can send you into a nice quest of understanding.

Comment: @alfa64: indeed. There's no point in reading all of the above and then thinking it will necessarily solve your problems. You're going to work on specific hardware, with specific platforms, specific software, specific environmental issues, and specific usage patterns. You need to identify your bottlenecks and know where they are. Also, the sad thing is that sometimes optimizing a section that IS NOT a bottleneck will make another bottleneck worth (think of traffic lights, for instance: they may look like they slow you down in one spot, but it's to optimize a wider design).

Comment: @haylem I will give it a couple of days. I just wanted to thank you for a great answer.

Comment: @user745434: Sure. Again, glad it helped (and thanks for letting me know, it's nice to have feedback.)